# vectorization for array products

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How can I vectorize this loop ?

Let `b` = real array of size (2,3)

`M` = real array of size (7,2)

`y` = real array of size (n,3)

`b` and `M` are constant and `n` is "big" (in my problem, n > 80000).

I want to optimize (vectorize) this loop :

```
for k=1:max(size(y))
    r=b*y(k,:)';
    p(k)=r'*M;
end
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Isn't `b*y(k,:)` a problem (i.e. *2*-by-*3 x 1*-by-*3*)? Don't you need to transpose `y(k,:)`?

Comment: Sure ... there is a mistake : it's r=b*y(k,:)' instead of r=b*y(k,:). I forgot the transposition ... Sorry

Comment: Is it not then `p=(b*y')'*M`?

Comment: Yes ! But I need to vectorize the loop. Any idea ?

Comment: yes, that is the vectorization. Just that line, no loop needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first p(K)=r'*M is wrong

(b*y(k,:)' is (2X1) and M is (7X2))

so i think you mean p(k)=r'*M';

then

b is (2X3)

y is (nX3)

r= b*y' is (2Xn)

r' is (nX2)

M' is (2X7)

p=r'*M' is (nX7)

so you don't need to use for loop and can simply write:

p=(b*y')'*M'
or
p=(M*(b*y'))'